# OrientDB Time Series Data

Tags: graph, time-series, orientdb

I have seen the example of using OrientDB to model time series data but I don't know what the insertion looks like.

It would be great if somebody had an example for this.

Regards,
Tom

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Time-series-use-case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get a clearer idea of the utility of the Time Series, you could imagine this casuistry:

You have a given log related to a certain date. In the case where the DB had millions of records, a search through the date field would be very expensive as it would force the query to read all the records and check the condition, while with the time series filtering takes place at each passage between connected classes ( years, months, hours and then logs), so after going to read only the records that match the date and not all the others.

Following a small example:

```
CREATE CLASS Year extends V
CREATE CLASS Month extends V
CREATE CLASS Day extends V
CREATE CLASS Hour extends V
CREATE CLASS Log extends V

CREATE PROPERTY Year.value STRING
CREATE PROPERTY Year.month LINKMAP Month
CREATE PROPERTY Month.day LINKMAP Day
CREATE PROPERTY Day.hour LINKMAP Hour
CREATE PROPERTY Hour.log LINKSET Log

CREATE VERTEX Log SET priority='high'
CREATE VERTEX Log SET priority='medium'
CREATE VERTEX Log SET priority='low'

INSERT INTO Hour(log) VALUES ([#16:0,#16:1])
INSERT INTO Hour(log) VALUES ([#16:2])
INSERT INTO Day(hour) VALUES ({'15':#15:0})
INSERT INTO Day(hour) VALUES ({'10':#15:1})
INSERT INTO Month(day) VALUES ({'4':#14:0})
INSERT INTO Month(day) VALUES ({'21':#14:1})
INSERT INTO Year(value,month) VALUES ('2012',{'3':#13:0})
INSERT INTO Year(value,month) VALUES ('2015',{'8':#13:1})
```

**Query 1**: Find all the logs related to the date 4/3/2012 h15

```
SELECT EXPAND(month[3].day[4].hour[15].log) FROM Year WHERE value='2012'
```

**Query 2**: Find all the logs related to the date 21/8/2015 h10

```
SELECT EXPAND(month[8].day[21].hour[10].log) FROM Year WHERE value='2015'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @TommyK, did you have a chance to try my solution ?

Comment: the values in the brackets have to be quoted `SELECT EXPAND(month["3"].day["4"].hour["15"].log) FROM Year WHERE value='2012'`